# How to define JS Fixed Array Size?

Tags: javascript

how the fixed array size is defined. 
When data is added. The most recent data will be added to the last value and the first value will be ejected.

I think it will be solved by determining a fixed array, but I can't.

I have looked at similar questions but did not meet my needs.

I want to do.

A loop adds continuous value to the array. (Total of 50)

I want to move a row to the left when the most current value is added to the 50th value. ( pop,push )

Can you show a sample application? Thank you so much.

In short, I'm trying to implement the following algorithm.

[image]

Comment: new Array(50); will define array of length 50

Comment: Can you just check if you have more items than the maximum and then eject the first items from your array? You have the `length` property to do the checking against, push puts it at the end, you can then either `splice` for inplace mutation or `slice` to create a new array

Comment: Where's the Javascript? Have you tried anything at yourself yeT?

Comment: you can take a look of this article, this may help you implementing the stack. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-stack-javascript/

Comment: I don't see anything in the "algorithm" picture that describes ejecting values or a fixed/maximum amount of elements. It's just two *independent* operations, `stack.push(dataElement)` and `dataElement = stack.pop()`

Comment: @priyanshisrivastava new Array(50) will only set the initial size of the array not what op is asking

Comment: Actually from the textual description, I thought you were describing a queue first, and not a stack

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski yes I understood that later when he described more

Answer (score 0):

You should not fix the size but still you want then you can use

```
new Array(5);
```

It will create empty array of length 5